# torch cannot allocate small size tensor (< 1GB) on GPU but it can for CPU on the same node with 400+ GB memory on databricks

Tags: pytorch, gpu, tensor, torch

My question is relevant to my previous one [pytorch allocate memory for small size tensor on cpu and gpu but got error on a node with more than 400 GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64869711/pytorch-allocate-memory-for-small-size-tensor-on-cpu-and-gpu-but-got-error-on-a).
But, it is different so I created a new thread.

In this question, I have changed size of the input tensor size.

```
 import torch
 from torch import nn
 import numpy as np
 num_embedding, num_dim = 14000, 300
 embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embedding, num_dim)

 row, col = 8000, 302
 t = [[x for x in range(col)] for _ in range(row)] 
 
 t1 = torch.tensor(t)
 print(t1.shape)  # torch.Size([8000, 302])

 type(t1), t1.device, (t1.nelement() * t1.element_size())/(1024**3) # (torch.Tensor, device(type='cpu'), 0.01800060272216797)

 tt = embedding(t1)
 embedding.forward(t1)

 t2 = t1.cuda()
 t2.device, t2.shape, t2.grad, t2.nelement(), t2.element_size(), (t2.nelement() * t2.element_size())/(1024**3) # (device(type='cuda', index=0), torch.Size([8000, 302]), None, 2416000, 8, 0.01800060272216797)

 embedding_cuda = embedding.cuda()
 torch.cuda.empty_cache()
 embedding_cuda(t2) # RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.70 GiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 7.19 GiB already allocated; 2.01 GiB free; 8.88 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Why the small size tensor (0.018 GB) can be allocated to cpu but cannot be allocated to gpu on the same node (p2.8xlarge) ? why it requires 2.7 GB, which 100 times larger than its original size at least ?

I have checked most posts at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RuntimeError%3A+CUDA+out+of+memory.+Tried+to+allocate+GiB
but, none of them can help me about this.